# Jekyll: Week numbers in Europe

Tags: timezone, jekyll, week-number

for my Jekyll project I need to work with week numbers for certain dates. The problem is that the returned week number does not match with the german one.

I have set the timezone in config.yml:

`timezone: Europe/Berlin`

For example:

`{{ 2019-12-31 | date: "%W" }}`
returns
`52`

1 would be correct. I've tested this on various dates. The week number is never matching, always shifted by 1 or 2 numbers. Does anyone have any idea how to fix the problem?

Thanks!
S.

Comment: You may want to try `%V`...? https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/5981/files

Comment: works! Thank you so much! :)